# T- Sql aggregate query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong with this query.I am trying to filter some records from a table that contains emails sent out to clients with the status of the emails.I need to eliminate all EmailIds that has a status of Sent(1) and Bounced(0). Anything other than these two statuses are considered as Delivered(4). So the output contains  only EmailId with a status of Delivered(4) for all those EmailIds that doesnt have statuses of 1 and 0.In the example below,I should see EmailId 4 too with a Status of Delivered

This is my sample set up.Really appreciate any help you guys can provide me with

```
create table #status
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(100)
)

insert into #status (Id, Name)
values (0, 'Bounced'), (1, 'Sent'), (2, 'Clicked'),
       (3, 'Opened'), (4, 'Delivered')

create table #email
(
    EmailId int ,
    Email varchar(100),
    StatusId int 
)

insert into #email (EmailId, email, StatusId)
values (1, 'rjoseph@gmail.com', 1), (1, 'rjoseph@gmail.com', 0),
       (2, 'nathan@comcast.net', 1), (2, 'nathan@comcast.net', 2),
       (2, 'nathan@comcast.net', 3), (3, 'nora@comcast.net', 1),
       (3, 'nora@comcast.net', 2), (3, 'nora@comcast.net', 3),
       (4, 'neha@comcast.net', 1)

select
    e.EmailId
into 
    #temp
from
    #email e
inner join #status st
    on st.Id = e.StatusId
where
    (e.StatusId not in (1,0))
group by
    e.EmailId

drop table #temp
drop table #email
drop table #status
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you are attempting to accomplish. This seems to be a pretty straightforward request but with a needlessly complicated solution. You have multiple SELECT statements returning three separate result sets. If you are just trying to filter out 0 and 1 statuses, you are already doing that in your first SELECT query (except you insert those rows into a temporary table, so you never see them).

Comment: @Boyd,I just got rid of the extra select statements that I had.I am trying to eliminate any EmaiId that has both 0 and 1 statusIds.Anything other than those should show up with EmailId in one column and Status of Delivered(4) on the next column(No duplicate EmailIds) .I don't see EmailId 4 with my aggreate query

Comment: Ahh, I see. The reason you don't see EmailID 4 is because you filter it out with the WHERE e.StatusId NOT IN(1,0). That's an OR statement, essentially saying "where the statusID is not 1 OR 0". I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Boyd

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a kludgy way to get to this (you can do this without the temporary tables, but I'm doing that here to follow your own syntax). The first query grabs the rows which match 1 AND 0. The second query returns the email IDs which do not exist in the first query:

```
SELECT EmailID
INTO #temp
FROM #email
WHERE StatusID = 0
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #email WHERE StatusID = 1)

SELECT DISTINCT e.EmailID
FROM #email AS e LEFT JOIN #temp AS t
ON e.EmailID = t.EmailID
WHERE t.EmailID IS NULL
```

BTW: The SELECT 1 FROM ... does not have anything to do with the StatusID #1. It may seem confusing because I used SELECT 1, but it could have been SELECT 5 or SELECT 'Z'. It's mostly meaningless.

Here's the same query without the temporary table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.EmailID
FROM #email AS e 
WHERE e.EmailID NOT IN (
  SELECT EmailID
  FROM #email
  WHERE StatusID = 0
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #email WHERE StatusID = 1)
)
```

Comment: ,thanks a lot.I have a starting point with this query to fix my bigger issue.Really appreciate you helping me out